# Updating Python in my folder on the cluster

Tags: python-2.7, cluster-computing, python-2.6, updating, environment-modules

I want to run a program on our cluster environment which requires python 2.7. The thing is the version installed on the cluster is 2.6.6. Therefore, I tried to update the python version in my own folder. To do so, first I used `module avail python` command, but nothing showed up!!! Afterward, I tried `which python2.7` on the command line, and I noticed that it exist in `/usr/bin/python2.7`. Going into the given subfolder, I tried `module load python2.7` but I faced the following error:

`ModuleCmd_Load.c(208):ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'python2.7'`

I would be very thankful if someone could tell me how can I solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `module` command you use needs to find a `modulefile` for the module python2.7 you try to load. If such modulefile is found it usually updates the shell environment to active the software in question.

In the situation you describe, it seems there is no python module available by default currently. Which means you either:

- need to find the modulepath to activate with the `module use` command where those python modulefiles are located
- or write a modulefile to enable this python2.7 installation and save it in an existig modulepath directory